# How to convert raw Database query to Query Builder in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, query-builder

Good day. Please how can I convert a raw sql query to Laravel query builder. With the raw sql, I am unable to paginate, and the data are quite numerous.

```
$cpCounsel = DB::table('cp_counsel as A')
    ->select([
        'A.enrolment_number as id',
        DB::raw('MIN(A.counsel) as counsel'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('enrolment_number');

$counsels = DB::table('cp_cases_counsel as T')
    ->joinSub($cpCounsel, 'A.id', '=', 'T.counsel_id')
    ->where('A.counsel', 'like', "%$request->search_term%")
    ->select([
        'T.counsel_id',
        'A.counsel',
        DB::raw('COUNT(T.counsel_id) as total'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 2, 1, 0)) as supreme_court_cases'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 2, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 1, 1, 0)) as supreme_court_cases_as_lead'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 2, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 2, 1, 0)) as supreme_court_cases_as_supporting'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 1, 1, 0)) as appeal_court_cases'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 1, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 1, 1, 0)) as appeal_court_cases_as_lead'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 1, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 2, 1, 0)) as appeal_court_cases_as_supporting'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('T.counsel_id', 'A.counsel')
    ->paginate(15);
```

I have modified @MohammedHassan's reply. Thanks

Comment: All you need is a ORDER BY and a LIMIT to make a query paginatable

Comment: @RiggsFolly, if I do that, how do I determine how the data will be fetched? If I use limit it won't be dynamic

Comment: You remember the number of rows per page and the page you are on (or want to be on) in sesssion

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, SQL statements have equivalent in [Laravel query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) and when you need to use a function you wrap your statement in `DB::raw()`.

Your query can be rewritten like this:

```php
$cpCounsel = DB::table('cp_counsel as A')
    ->select([
        'A.enrolment_number as id',
        DB::raw('MIN(A.counsel) as counsel'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('enrolment_number');

$counsels = DB::table('cp_cases_counsel as T')
    ->joinSub($cpCounsel, 'A.id', '=', 'T.counsel_id')
    ->where('A.counsel', 'like', "%$request->search_term%")
    ->select([
        'T.counsel_id',
        'A.counsel',
        DB::raw('COUNT(T.counsel_id) as total'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 2, 1, 0)) as supreme_court_cases'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 2, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 1, 1, 0)) as supreme_court_cases_as_lead'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 2, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 2, 1, 0)) as supreme_court_cases_as_supporting'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 1, 1, 0)) as appeal_court_cases'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 1, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 1, 1, 0)) as appeal_court_cases_as_lead'),
        DB::raw('SUM(if(T.court_id = 1, 1, 0) AND if(T.counsel_role = 2, 1, 0)) as appeal_court_cases_as_supporting'),
    ])
    ->groupBy('T.counsel_id', 'A.counsel')
    ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: You can also keep your solution and create a paginator [manually](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got this using laravel DB joinSub method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).